# Use Visual Studio debugger in Makefile-based solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, makefile, virtualbox

I have a huge Makefile-based project (actually [VirtualBox OSE](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)), a lot of executables, static and dynamic libraries (assume without drivers for a while). The actual problem is debugging.

I know WinDbg enough to do it, but everyone knows it's less user-friendly and convenient than VS debugger. Moreover, Microsoft C++ compiler is used, and as far as I understand, I have everything I need for debugging, sources, binaries in Release configuration, pdb-files and Visual Studio installation (it requires VS 2010, unfortunately without possibility to upgrade). Is there any way to debug using Visual Studio and use all the power of its IDE and debugger?

Manual converting is not an option at all, it has more than 400 Mb sources and hundreds of targets.

Comment: Are you aware that you can attach VS Debugger to a running process? [MSDN: Attach to Running Processes with the Visual Studio Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx). I use this from time to time but never yet with a program not built with a VS solution. On the other hand, I don't know why it shouldn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may work, no promises.

This assumes you've built the executable with correct debugging flags: `/ZI` at a minimum, `/Zi` will make your life orders of magnitude easier for hot-patching while debugging.  And the appropriate `/DEBUG` option to the linker.

Open a command prompt in the folder where you want the executable to run, and then type

```
<Path to Visual Studio.exe> <Path to your executable>
```

For example for an app I'm debugging that's:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" sspf.exe
```

That'll open visual studio, and if you hit F-10 it'll step into your program, and you should see source.

If that works, you should be good to go.  It'll ask if you want to save a `.sln` file on exit, it's up to you if you do.  If you don't, you will need to explicitly name the executable every time you start a new debug session, if you do, you'll have an additional file or files cluttering up your workspace, but will have the advantage that double clicking the `.sln` file will get you right back into a debug session.

For your case, this is a total non-issue, but it is worth noting that the `.sln` file created by doing this is only useful to debug the program, it can't be used to build it.

Comment: At last I managed to start it in debugger. There were complications, but in general you were right. The only problem for a while is that Win32 GUI application is started like a console app

Comment: Last problem solved without any effort from my side, just restarted the debugger. VirtualBox is a project whose work sometimes depends on stars positioning on the sky